# TYPO3 6.0: How to include php script

Tags: php, typo3

At my local machine I imported the database I downloaded from my site (TYPO3 4.1.6).
Then I solved all the minor problems I got and it is up and running very well.  Then I installed TYPO3 6.0.4 at the server in a subdomain and imported the new database.  It works just fine except for a plugin that doesn't work: Lumonet PHP Include.

In fact I could test the script after fixing a line in that extension but once installed it is not possible to add a new record due to a problem with another deprecated function that so far seems to be impossible to fix.

I need to run a php script in two pages but don't know how to do it. There is no new extension to include php scripts other than Lumonet, so I'm stuck.

I have read that such an script could be included using Typoscript but I don't know how to do it cause I coded some Typoscript years ago by mostly copy pasting snippets.

Any help on this regard will be very appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: As this has been solved to your satisfaction, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can include custom PHP function using a [USER or USER_INT content object](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html). An example is given on that page.

Comment: Thanks Jost, but I solved in an easier way. I placed an iframe tag in an HTML record.